# How to get environment variable from FastCGI C++ binary during startup

Tags: c++, fastcgi, lighttpd, getenv

I have a FastCGI application that loads and processes a lot of data during its startup. And I want it to get some environment variable to determine its input data path, but as much as I understand so far, environment pointer envp comes with the request.

I want to do getenv before the very first request, say directly after FCGX_Init(). Is it possible?

Comment: from the fastcgi faq "To pass or set an environment variable to a FastCGI application use the -initial-env argument to FastCgiConfig or FastCgiServer"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, as it turnes out, the lighttpd's counterpart to -initial-env is "bin-environment" array in the fastcgi.server section of lighttpd.conf. The values defined there are accessible for getenv() from the very beginning of execution.